# React - UseEffect enforce execution order

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, jwt

I'm new to React and I'm using React + Redux (+django DRF) and JWT authentication with refresh.

I created an action `refreshToken`  so that when this action is called, if the refresh token is still valid, it makes a post request to obtain a new pair of tokens. (if the token is expired then the user is logged out).

Now, I want this to be executed before I send a request to any of my api routes that require authentication.

I'm calling the refresh action with dispatch in useEffect, before calling the protected api. However, most times, the request for the protected api `myProtectedGETapi`  is executed before my `refreshToken`  action.

```
useEffect(() => {
        
        if (userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin ){
            dispatch(refreshToken())
            dispatch(myProtectedGETapi())
        }else{
            navigate('/login')
        }

    },[dispatch, navigate, userInfo])
```

So I would like to enfore an execution order within useEffect, so to first check and refresh the token, and then execute the second api call

Is this possible?
Or what is the best practice to implement this logic in React+Redux ?

Comment: The state is a snapshot in time. What can you add to the state to track whether a refresh token is needed? Dispatches are async and may even be batched (they all run, then a re-render happens) so trying to determine order via other means may not work out super great.

Comment: That does make sense! How would you do about solving the problem without the use of dispatch? I was looking into axios interceptors, but haven't managed to get it to work yet

Comment: I would still dispatch, just not two at one time. So there's be one more `else` in your code there checking for whatever state I had to represent the token.

Comment: Although now that I'm thinking about it, I'd probably have a more robust thing for tokens similar to this https://www.bezkoder.com/react-refresh-token/ if I were using axios. They have interceptors.